# Textarea won't show anything inside of it when used with asp-for in razor-pages ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, textarea, razor-pages

The HTML tag `<input>` works fine and displays the data inside of it, but when I am using `<textarea>` it doesn't work and it probably does not work with asp-for but I'm still forced to use asp-for because I'm using .NET Core to build the web-page.

This is the output code that is malfunctioning (.cshtml)

```
@foreach (ComplaintManagement.Context.notesData note in ViewBag.getID)
                    {
                        <label>Subject</label>
                        <input required="required" class="form-control" asp-for="subject" value="@note.subject" />
                        <label>Summary</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control mb-2" asp-for="summary" rows="10">@note.summary</textarea>
                    }
```

If I failed to explain what I meant, hope the picture I attached helps...[image]

If more information is needed, please ask in the comment section.

Comment: Maybe you can show us the Page Model(malfunctioning.cs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out an answer myself, instead of using asp-for I used this

```
<label>Summary</label>
<textarea class="form-control mb-2" rows="10" name="@Html.NameFor(m => m.summary)">@note.summary</textarea>
```

Using `name=""` instead of `asp-for=""` for the textarea solved the issue.

Comment: Yes @FahadAzeem, if you don't use asp-for then there won't be an issue. Using name is also legit option.

Answer (score 0):

In normal scenario:

```
<textarea name='awesome'>Default value</textarea>
```

But in your case:

.NET Core developers who use asp-for must use a constructor in the model class to set the default value.

Example:

```
public class Service()
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    //other properties

    public Service() //the constructor
    {
      Description = "Put the default value here!";
      //other default values
     }
}
```

Comment: It does not have a default value, I think I will need to pass the value from view to model?

Comment: `public class notesData
    {

        
        [Key]

        public int noteId { get; set; }

        public string subject { get; set; }

        public string summary { get; set; }
        public int userID { get; set; }

        notesData()

        {

            summary = "What to do here? How do I get the value from view?";

        }

}`

Comment: Can you try:

<textarea class="form-control mb-2" asp-for="@Model.summary" rows="10"></textarea>

Comment: Also try: <textarea class="form-control mb-2" asp-for="@Model.summary" rows="10">@Model.summary</textarea>

Let me know if any of them works out.